# Scanner not finding blank lines, returning index out of bounds

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file line by line and take action on every line that begins with the character 'Q'. I keep getting this error after trying many solutions from SO and the JavaDoc. I cannot figure out for the life of me what I am getting it. My method looks like this:

```
public Question makeQuestion(){
    //scanner checks line and takes action
    while(fileScan.hasNextLine()){

        //save the line
        String line = fileScan.nextLine();

        //if line is blank move on to next line
        if(line.isEmpty()) fileScan.nextLine();

        //if line starts with Q do something
        if(line.charAt(0) == 'Q'){
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    }
```

The method finds the first line that begins with Q but fails after that. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `if(line.isEmpty()) fileScan.nextLine();` What if the nextLine is also empty / null?. What if there is no next line?  BTW what is the error?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to execute a send nextLine() within your loop.

Try this:

```
while(fileScan.hasNextLine()){

    //save the line
    String line = fileScan.nextLine();

    //if line is NOT empty AND starts with Q do something
    if(!line.isEmpty() && line.charAt(0) == 'Q'){
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Question makeQuestion(){
    //scanner checks line and takes action
    while(fileScan.hasNextLine()){

        //save the line
        String line = fileScan.nextLine();


        //if line starts with Q do something
        if(line != null && !line.isEmpty() && line.charAt(0) == 'Q'){
            System.out.println(line);
        }

}
```

If you call nextLine in the loop twice it is possible that you reach the last line in your first call.

in that case, the second call will throw the exception because there is no next line.

Comment: I'd throw in a null check as well.

Comment: well yeah... should not occure but doesnt hurt

Answer (score 0):

You should not read the line again if it is empty.

```
public Question makeQuestion(){
//scanner checks line and takes action
while(fileScan.hasNextLine()){

    //save the line
    String line = fileScan.nextLine();

    //if line starts with Q do something
    if(!line.isEmpty() && line.charAt(0) == 'Q'){
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic here,

```
if(line.isEmpty()) fileScan.nextLine();
```

is incorrect (for one thing, it doesn't update `line` so you then output blank lines). The easiest solution is probably to use,

```
if(line.isEmpty()) continue;
```

Comment: you should NEVER use continue IMHO

Comment: @PhilippSander I (personally) disagree with your opinion on that. It's not even a labelled continue!

Comment: @PhilippSander - Oh.. If it could come in handy if there are several lines of code following it.

Comment: @PhilippSander why should you never use `continue`?

Comment: It depends on the use, but it is sometimes considered a bad practice http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices